# Using Random in C# with loop between 2 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, loops, random

Thank you all for your comment's and answers, I have this project for monthly employee shifts,
I wrote some code, but I got some things wrong, like some Employee are repeating in the same month and that's not supposed to happend.
I have more than 100 employees in my table called 'EmployeeTB', and I want to put them in 'ShiftTB', which contains shifts for one month, one by one without repeating employees when I use `Random.Next()`

here's my code that generates my shifts and it's correct:

```
private void PopulateDate(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
{
    var dt1 = FromDate;
    var dt2 = ToDate;
    var dt = FromDate;
    if (dt <= ToDate)
    {
        dt = dt.AddDays(-1);
        while (dt2 >= dt1)
        {
            List<ShiftTB> ResultList = new List<ShiftTB>
            {
                new ShiftTB { NameOfDay = dt1.DayOfWeek.ToString(), DateOfDay = dt=dt.AddDays(1) },
            };
            foreach (var item in ResultList)
            {

                dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1);
                db.ShiftTBs.InsertOnSubmit(item);
            }
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code that needs correcting:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
PopulateDate(DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text), DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text));

var EmpList = db.EmployeeTBs.Where(x => x.EmpType == "1" && x.Empstatus == "ok").ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < EmpList.Count; i++)
{
    int x = rnd.Next(0, EmpList.Count());
    var ListOfResult = db.ShiftTBs.Where(lor => lor.EmpName == null).ToList();
    ListOfResult[x].EmpID = EmpList[i].EmpID;
    ListOfResult[x].EmpName = EmpList[i].EmpName;
    ListOfResult[x].EmpDepartment = EmpList[i].DepartmentName;
    ListOfResult[x].EmpType = EmpList[i].EmpType;
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here's it :

```
Random rnd=new Random();
    var EmpList = db.EmployeeTBs.Where(x => x.EmpType == "1" && x.Empstatus == "ok").ToList();
int n = EmpList.Count;
While (n>1){
   n--;
int k = rnd.Next(n+1);
var value = EmpList[k];
EmpList[k] = EmpList[n];
EmpList[n] = value;
}
    var ListOfResult = db.ShiftTBs.Where(lor => lor.EmpName == null).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < ListOfResult.Count; i++)
    {
        var empId = i % EmpList.Count;
        ListOfResult[i].EmpID = EmpList[empId].EmpID;
        ListOfResult[i].EmpName = EmpList[empId].EmpName;
        ListOfResult[i].EmpDepartment = EmpList[empId].DepartmentName;
        ListOfResult[i].EmpType = EmpList[empId].EmpType;
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: This is horrible code, btw. You're mutating IDs in a database record and setting a lot of denormalized data into the database.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's work with me so if you don't like it don't leave comment here , thanks

Comment: No, it's not a person thing. It's about helping future readers know if this is a good solution. I'm not criticising you, just the code. I'd recommend that you try to write more modular code. A Sad Shoe's code was better because the shuffle was encapsulated in `void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) `.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the list randomized you can use an extension method like the one mentioned in Ken-Y-N's comment (snippet below for the easy version)

```
private static Random rng = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

This performs a pseudo-random shuffle, which should be plenty for your purposes, if you wanna stick to your own method of generating the randomness, then simply make sure you're marking your `Random` as static, so if won't grab the same seed etc.

With the above you can structure your code like so:

```
PopulateDate(DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text), DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text));

var EmpList = db.EmployeeTBs.Where(x => x.EmpType == "1" && x.Empstatus == "ok").ToList();
EmpList.Shuffle();
var ListOfResult = db.ShiftTBs.Where(lor => lor.EmpName == null).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < ListOfResult.Count; i++)
{
    var empId = i % EmpList.Count;
    ListOfResult[i].EmpID = EmpList[empId].EmpID;
    ListOfResult[i].EmpName = EmpList[empId].EmpName;
    ListOfResult[i].EmpDepartment = EmpList[empId].DepartmentName;
    ListOfResult[i].EmpType = EmpList[empId].EmpType;
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

This is assuming that you want the list of employees shuffled, and then spacing them out as evenly as possible, if you want it completely random after the list is shuffled you can also do a `Random.Next()` call as the employee id, but it's up to you.
As always, I don't know your exact issue and goal, so take it with a grain of salt

Comment: thank you for your answer but i get error on EmpList.Shuffle(); 
My issue is  : 
I have more than 100 employees and I want to distribute them on the days of the month so that they do not repeat during this month

Comment: the extension method should work, and i can see that it's the exact same way you've done it in your own answer, note that you need to put a static extension method into it's own static class if you want to be able to use it that way, also if you've solved the issue, please mark the answer as such